# How do I read the second line of multiple TXT files using cat and output the results?

Tags: awk, cat

How do I read the second line of multiple files and then output the results to a TXT file?

I can read the second line of one file so far, using:

```
cat file-1.txt | awk 'NR == 2'
```

But, it's reading the second line of hundreds of files and writing the results to a TXT file where I am stuck.

```
cat file-1.txt | awk 'NR == 2'
cat file-2.txt | awk 'NR == 2'
...
cat file-199.txt | awk 'NR == 2'
cat file-200.txt | awk 'NR == 2'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With your shown samples try, following `awk` code, written and tested in GNU `awk`. Simply just read only 2nd line of each file(since `FNR` is the variable which gets reset after each file's start) if its value is `2` the print that line and use `nextfile` which will take cursor to next file and skip all the lines to save some cycles and time.

Since `awk` can read multiple files within itself so passing `*.txt` to it here. And when reading files from `awk` we need not to use `cat` command, since `awk` can read file(s) itself.

```
awk 'FNR==2{print;nextfile}' *.txt
```